# Django: Shopping site similar to eBay

Tags: python, django, frameworks, e-commerce

I need to build a site similar to ebay. I've found some "e-commerce" packages for Django but those are not related to the "C2C" model from eBay.

I've tried these:

https://www.django-shop.org/

http://www.satchmoproject.com/

Do you know any app (package, framework) that can deal with it? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While this is a frequently asked-for application, it doesn't appear as if anyone has actually implemented it.

It doesn't seem like that hard a project.  You would need a Profile app to track the user's reputation, a messaging app (easily available), a Products app (users offer products, users bid on products, at a given time the bidding is closed, etc...).

A weekend for the basics, I think.  Rip the Hell out of Satchmo for your transaction handling, and get a real authorization account through Authorize.NET, not some Google Checkout or Paypal thingy.  You'd be on the hook for one big fraud risk, though, which is why auction sites are generally for the Big Kids.

Comment: Thank you Elf. I'm not planning to take care of the payment. That would be arranged by the seller and the buyer. That way will be simpler for me. I think i'll build it myself. Will take some more time, but it worth it. Have you tried Pinax?

Comment: Sure.  It's a good framework.  But you'd still have to build the negotiation part yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a near similar solution for you: [Collector City Marketplace](https://github.com/StephenPower/CollectorCity-Market-Place)

Comment: @santiagobasulto As I see you asked it 1 year ago!:) Have you done any progress since then? Have Open Sourced your code?